# TypeScript compile error in underscore.d.ts on hosted build controller in Visual Studio Online

Tags: underscore.js, typescript, azure-devops, definitelytyped

I have an Azure website connected to Visual Studio Online. When connecting the two, Visual Studio Online creates a continuous delivery build run on the hosted build controller. This build keeps failing with a single typescript compile error in underscore.d.ts (a TypeScript type definition from http://definitelytyped.org/), which reads as follows:

> \Scripts\typings\underscore\underscore.d.ts(2315,1): error TS2160: Build: A generic type may not reference itself with a wrapped form of its own type parameters.

We use TypeScript 1.0:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

The project builds without errors both locally and on our on-premises TFS build server. My guess is that the problem lies with the TypeScript compiler version in Visual Studio Online.

My question is whether there is a workaround for this problem. Is there, for example. the possibility of conditionally excluding underscore.d.ts from building?

Comment: I filed a [bug report for this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/915464/underscore-d-ts-compiles-offline-but-not-online).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to provision your own TypeScript compiler. TypeScript is available in [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) and it is easy enough to compile TypeScript that way using an appropriate plugin to [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), as two examples. You could add npm and gulp/grunt as a prebuild script or as custom actions in your workflow. (I've automated TypeScript compiles with r.js optimization into Azure git deploys using npm and grunt.)

Answer (score 0):

The bug is now [fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/915464/underscore-d-ts-compiles-offline-but-not-online). No workaround required. Happy building in the cloud!